# InDesign: how to mark lines for printing cuts?

Tags: adobe-indesign, print-production

How can I insert printing marks to designate a smaller format than the page size? 
Printing shop insists that for making a 7x5 inch print they need me to insert it into an A5 document. So placed it as they said, but am a bit uncertain how I could mark for them where the paper needs to be cut.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Add a new Swatch (any color) and make it a 'Spot' color.
- Draw a 7x5 inch rectangle in the middle of the A5 sheet and stroke it with this new swatch.
- Set the rectangle stroke to 'Overprint' via the 'Attributes' panel.
- Place your artwork inside the rectangle.
- Export to PDF.

Answer (score 1):

You just put bleed/cut marks on it. There is indesign script for that in 'Scripts → Application → Samples' to create the marks on additional layer. Or to make things easier set your page size to 7x5inch and then just set bleed to A5 size. So when you export your pdf just tick the cut marks.

Answer (score 1):

There is also another, low-tech solution to that issue.

1. Make a document in the size you eventually need
2. Apply Bleed marks
3. Save as pdf/jpeg/etc., including the printing marks
4. Create a new file, size as desired by the printing shop
5. Place your document, keeping its size. Adjust position according to printer's wishes.

Keep in mind that the new document also ought to have bleeding marks, so if you align the actual file to any of the edges, then you need to make the bleed section overlap on that edge as well.