# How do you view printers marks while editing?

Tags: adobe-indesign

In InDesign, I can export OK with printers marks.  However, I've seen people working in the editor with the printers marks still visible.  How can I do that?

I've tried Bleed Preview Mode/Slug Preview Mode, but these don't show the other printers marks.

By printers marks, I meant the full set as demonstrated [here](https://helpx.adobe.com/indesign/using/printers-marks-bleeds.html).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [InDesign: how to mark lines for printing cuts?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/90381/indesign-how-to-mark-lines-for-printing-cuts) @SZCZERZO KŁY's answer explain where is the CropMarks script

Comment: That seems to add Crop marks, but no other printers marks?  eg https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/b/printer-s-marks-5929762.jpg

Comment: Export empty page and place back to Indesign into a Master page.

Comment: Just curious... Why do you want to see all marks while editing? They lie outside the cropped area, so they shouldn't have any effect on your design. I've never heard of a print house who wants more than just crop marks anyway.

Comment: @Wolff, yea that's what I thought. Document border is where the Crop marks land and the Bleed border is where the Bleed marks land, so those shouldn't be needed at all before export. What any of the other printer marks could bring to the table when designing it... I have no idea.

Comment: I agree it's not hugely useful, but we just wanted to know how it was done after seeing it at one site (:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is not an Indesign feature. There are some third part plugins to buy, like [Cacidi](http://www.cacidi.com/products/cacidi-cropmarks-cc/) at www.cacidi.com, which add a submenu at the Objects Menu with several printed marks options.

> Cacidi Cropmarks is very easy to use, create a setting you like as described on top, and press the Apply button in the Cacidi dialog box, or just select the Apply Cropmarks, in the menu Object->Cacidi Cropmarks.
>
> To apply crop marks, just select an object, or multiple objects and crop marks will be applied to the object/objects.
>
> All elements will be placed on a specific layer, and locked.

[image]